# Access XML Node with namespace in Groovy - XmlSlurper

Tags: groovy

Have an xml as below and I am trying to get the size of "TimeAccountDetail" but just get a 0 but expecting 2. No idea what needs to be done?

xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<multimap:Messages xmlns:multimap="http://sap.com/xi/XI/SplitAndMerge">
    <multimap:Message1>
        <TimeAccountDetail>
            <TimeAccountDetail>
                <TimeAccount_externalCode>614dbcc89cb843129b5c3be26dbd2a22</TimeAccount_externalCode>
                <bookingDate>2019-03-21T07:38:31</bookingDate>
                <bookingType>ADJUSTMENT</bookingType>
                <comment>This is my test1</comment>
                <employeeTime>null</employeeTime>
                <externalCode>MyTimeAccountDetail</externalCode>
                <referenceObject>null</referenceObject>
            </TimeAccountDetail>
        </TimeAccountDetail>
        <TimeAccountDetail>
            <TimeAccountDetail>
                <TimeAccount_externalCode>614dbcc89cb843129b5c3be26dbd2a22</TimeAccount_externalCode>
                <bookingDate>2019-03-21T07:38:31</bookingDate>
                <bookingType>ADJUSTMENT</bookingType>
                <comment>This is my test2</comment>
                <employeeTime>null</employeeTime>
                <externalCode>MyTimeAccountDetail</externalCode>
                <referenceObject>null</referenceObject>
            </TimeAccountDetail>
        </TimeAccountDetail>
    </multimap:Message1>
</multimap:Messages>
```

groovy:

```groovy
def ns = new Namespace('xmlns:http://sap.com/xi/XI/SplitAndMerge', 'multimap')
def slurper = new XmlSlurper(false,true)
def payload = slurper.parse(new File("C:/Users/me/Documents/finalXML.xml"))
def payloadSize = payload.TimeAccountDetail.size()
println "size is ${payloadSize}"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you just have to change this line in your code:

```
def payloadSize = payload.Message1.TimeAccountDetail.size()
```

because `TimeAccountDetail` located inside `Message1`

and if you want to make namespace-aware node lookup:

```
def slurper = new XmlSlurper(false,true)
def payload = slurper.parseText(xml).declareNamespace(x:'http://sap.com/xi/XI/SplitAndMerge')
def payloadSize = payload.'x:Message1'.TimeAccountDetail.size()
println "size is ${payloadSize}"
```

Comment: Thank You ! isnt it the same way I access the value of an element ? ` def String build_time=payload.Message1[0].TimeAccountDetail[i-1].bookingDate
            println "Date is ${build_time}" `  any help ? Cheers!

Comment: note that you have two nested elements `TimeAccountDetail`. so accessor should look like this: `payload.Message1[0].TimeAccountDetail[1].TimeAccountDetail.bookingDate`

Comment: btw, to iterate elements you could use `each` : `payload.Message1[0].TimeAccountDetail.each{ta-> println ta.TimeAccountDetail.bookingDate}`

Comment: Thank You heaps!!